# Sorting in dataview not happening properly(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the following

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r1");
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r2");
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r3");
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r4");

            dt.Rows.Add("2", "r1");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "r2");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "r3");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "r4");

            dt.Rows.Add("3", "r1");
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "r2");
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "r3");
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "r4");

            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r1");
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "r2");

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = "col1";

            DataTable dResult = dv.Table;
```

I am trying to sort the datatable with the help of dataview so that the result will be

```
1 r1
1 r2   
...

2 r1
2 r2
...

3 r1
3 r2
......
```

Means all 1's first followed by 2's and 3r's

Even I tried with `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "col1";` but no luck.

But it is not happening. Only the result i am able to view in `dv.Sort`  and not the datatable (dResult)

I am using C#3.0.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the 'col1' column to int instead of string.

Then enter those values as integers instead.

---

-Edit

Yea, that doesn't work.

dv.Table returns the Source table, not the sorted data.

Use this to get the sorted data.

```
DataTable dResult = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: sorry.. does not work.. and also I cannot chenge the datatype.. It is just a sample of the origional where the data is coming from excel file